# Pressure cooked chicken didn't reach 165 but just 160, is that okay?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, meat, food-science, temperature

Okay, I am going from vegetarian->non-vegeterian for the first time, so need some cooking advice.

While pressure cooking the chicken in instant pot, I pressure-cooked on high for about 15 mins, and did a quick release (just to note the temperature, didn't eat it).
The chicken wasn't frozen, just refrigerated.

My thermometer read only 160F and it quickly dropped to 140F in a few mins.

Should this be okay, or something of a concern? Is 15 min high pressure cook on instant pot okay, or should I increase like 20 mins etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You want to consider that food safety is a function of temperature and time, in other words, how long does it take to kill all<sup>1</sup> bacteria at a certain temperature. If you see only one number, that’s the simplified version where bacteria are killed instantly. There are tables and charts available from food safety agencies that take exactly that relationship into consideration.

[At 160F (71C), the hold time for chicken breasts is 15.3 seconds.](https://blog.thermoworks.com/chicken/chicken-internal-temps-everything-you-need-to-know/) I think it’s safe to say that that’s easily the time it took for the quick release. (The linked article has a table for chicken and a link to USDA guidelines.)

The main conclusion for cooks: it’s the time / temperature combination that allows us to produce safe meat dishes without overcooking our proteins.

———

<sup>1</sup> “all” is to be understood in a food safety sense, not as in a lab